# Detect what div 'id' or 'class' was clicked on page without jQuery

Tags: javascript, events, click

Is there a way to write an event on the page to listen for any and all clicks on the page and return their id or class name. I can't seem to find anything that does it without the use of jQuery. Example:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event)
    console.log(event.target.id)
    console.log(event.target.className);
});
```

Seems very simple but I am just having a hard time getting it to work. I have tried setting the event listener to the window as well.

Comment: Works for me after fixing the syntax error: http://jsfiddle.net/g82817Lz/

Comment: "hard time" - what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log(event.target.id)
    console.log(event.target.className);
});
```

missing `{`

Comment: It should be noted that this will not work in all browsers

Comment: Thanks sometimes when I copy code inside of the editor the formatting doesn't all come along so I may have accidentally deleted it during reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was clicking inside of an iframe and therefor it wasn't returning any values. Works outside of an iframe like intended. Thanks all!